# How to replace value in JSON object in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I want to replace the value in existing JSON object in Node.js

Code :

```
var designationName='Softwar Engineer';
console.log(generateData[0]);
```

Console Output:

```
{ 
email: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
designation: 10,
id: 274,
first_name: 'firstname',
mobile: '1234567890',
last_name: 'lastname'
}
```

In the above console output 'designation' value printed as '10'

Expected Result:

I want to replace "designation: Software Engineer" instead of "designation:10"

Comment: `generateData[0].designation = designationName;` ?

Comment: What has this got to do with JSON? There is no JSON in your example code.

Answer (score 3):

Considering generateData[0] contains the following json which you fetch from a database

```
 { 
  email: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
  designation: 10,
  id: 274,
  first_name: 'firstname',
  mobile: '1234567890',
  last_name: 'lastname'
 };
```

To replace "designation: Software Engineer" instead of "designation:10"

```
var designationName = 'Software Engineer';
if(generateData[0]){
 generateData[0]['designation']= designationName;
}
console.log(generateData[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var designationName='Softwar Engineer';
if( generateData.length && generateData[0].designation)
{
    generateData[0].designation = designationName;
}
console.log(generateData[0]);
```

Comment: Hi DinhNC, Thanks for your answer, but out put was look like in the below.    { 
email: 'shiva7202020@gmail.com',
designation: 10,
id: 274,
first_name: 'Siva',
mobile: '9942235226',
last_name: 'Palaniappan'
}

Comment: Hi DinhNC, Thanks for your answer, but output was look like in the below.   as { desigantion:NaN}

Comment: Can you share your code please! I think your running don't correct.
You can see example here: http://www.node-console.com/script/code

Copy code below for testing:
var generateData = [{ email: 'shiva7202020@gmail.com',
  designation: 10,
  id: 274,
  first_name: 'Siva',
  mobile: '9942235226',
  last_name: 'Palaniappan' }];

var designationName='Softwar Engineer';

generateData[0].designation = designationName;

console.log(generateData[0]);

Comment: Code for testing: http://www.mediafire.com/download/0xuri1718nfvp5q/ConsoleTest.zip

Comment: Your output was look like { desigantion:NaN}. Maybe storage structure type in DB don't correct or you try storing String into Number.

Comment: Yes , I tried to store string into number and now its working fine, Thank you